# Error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ( Me making a simple struct. )

Tags: struct

I was trying to make a simple struct to hold character stats.

This is what I came up with:

```
struct cStats
{
    int nStrength;
    int nIntelligence;
    int nMedical;
    int nSpeech;
    int nAim;
};

cStats mainchar;
mainchar.nStrength = 10;
mainchar.nIntelligence = 10;
mainchar.nMedical = 10;
mainchar.nSpeech = 10;
mainchar.nAim = 10;
```

The mainchar. part is underlined red in visual studio, and when I mouse over it it shows this:
Error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Any explanation of why it's doing this, and what I should be doing to fix it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If this is C you should tag your question as such. `cStats` is a structure tag, not a type specifier. You need to declare `mainchar` as:

```
struct cStats mainchar;
```

If you wanted to use `cStats` as a type specifier you would define it as:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int nStrength;
    int nIntelligence;
    int nMedical;
    int nSpeech;
    int nAim;
} cStats;
```

If you did that your `cStats mainchar` would work.

Note that in C, `char` and character mean “ASCII alphanumeric character”, not “character in a play or game”. I suggest coming up with a different term for your program.

Another bit of advice; do not prefix your names with their data type; like `nStrength` for integer Strength. The compiler will tell you if you get your data types wrong, and if you ever need to change a type, for example to `float nStrength` to handle fractional Strengths, changing the name will be a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
main(){
mainchar.nStrength = 10;
mainchar.nIntelligence = 10;
mainchar.nMedical = 10;
mainchar.nSpeech = 10;
mainchar.nAim = 10;}
```

These initialization should be written within the main() function.
Or else, write a init function and call it from main function.